# Iterating Through An Object / Array of Items

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to work on my Stripe Checkout Session, by passing an array of product data to the backend node.js server, and iterate over it.

I have my object of products like:

```
{
  products: [
    {
      _id: '62129d5184689c5c77eb8fed',
      title: 'GBOS Champion Tie Die Hoodie',
      description: 'Tie die has never looked better with this new style of hoodies from the collection',
      image: 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0002/9061/9452/products/unisex-champion-tie-dye-hoodie-navy-front-60831f17ab838_1200x1200.png?v=1619205920',
      categories: [Array],
      sizes: [Array],
      color: '',
      price: 54,
      createdAt: '2022-02-20T19:58:09.071Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-02-20T19:58:09.071Z',
      __v: 0,
      quantity: 1,
      size: ''
    },
    {
      _id: '62129d5184689c5c77eb8fed',
      title: 'GBOS Champion Tie Die Hoodie',
      description: 'Tie die has never looked better with this new style of hoodies from the collection',
      image: 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0002/9061/9452/products/unisex-champion-tie-dye-hoodie-navy-front-60831f17ab838_1200x1200.png?v=1619205920',
      categories: [Array],
      sizes: [Array],
      color: '',
      price: 54,
      createdAt: '2022-02-20T19:58:09.071Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-02-20T19:58:09.071Z',
      __v: 0,
      quantity: 1,
      size: ''
    },
    {
      _id: '62129d5184689c5c77eb8fed',
      title: 'GBOS Champion Tie Die Hoodie',
      description: 'Tie die has never looked better with this new style of hoodies from the collection',
      image: 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0002/9061/9452/products/unisex-champion-tie-dye-hoodie-navy-front-60831f17ab838_1200x1200.png?v=1619205920',
      categories: [Array],
      sizes: [Array],
      color: '',
      price: 54,
      createdAt: '2022-02-20T19:58:09.071Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-02-20T19:58:09.071Z',
      __v: 0,
      quantity: 1,
      size: ''
    },
    {
      _id: '62129d5184689c5c77eb8fed',
      title: 'GBOS Champion Tie Die Hoodie',
      description: 'Tie die has never looked better with this new style of hoodies from the collection',
      image: 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0002/9061/9452/products/unisex-champion-tie-dye-hoodie-navy-front-60831f17ab838_1200x1200.png?v=1619205920',
      categories: [Array],
      sizes: [Array],
      color: '',
      price: 54,
      createdAt: '2022-02-20T19:58:09.071Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-02-20T19:58:09.071Z',
      __v: 0,
      quantity: 1,
      size: ''
    }
  ]
}
```

and it is sent via the React.js front-end through:

```
  const handleStripe = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/stripe/checkout", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
              products: cart.products
          }),
      });
    }
```

I want to, in the node.js backend, iterate through each of the products and add them to the line items array Stripe needs, essentially like this:

```
router.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
    const products = req.body;

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({

        line_items: [
          {
            price_data: {
              currency: 'usd',
              product_data: {
                name: 'T-shirt',
              },
              unit_amount: 2000,
            },
            quantity: 1,
          },
          {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product_data: {
                    name: 'Mug',
                },
                unit_amount: 500,
            },
            quantity: 1,
          }
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cart',
      });
    
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
});
```

I keep getting products.map, products.forEach, etc. is not a method.

Edit: The code for mapping

```
const products = req.body.products;

    const items = products.map(product => {
        return {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product_data: {
                    name: product.name,
                },
                unit_amount: product.price * 100,
            },
            quantity: product.quantity,
        };
    });
```

The console prints out:

```
[
  {
    price_data: { currency: 'usd', product_data: [Object], unit_amount: 14599 },
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    price_data: { currency: 'usd', product_data: [Object], unit_amount: 3599 },
    quantity: 1
  }
]
(node:5263) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: you cannot map object. need array. you will need to map through Object.keys(products)

Comment: You have not included the related code that contains a map or forEach.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to map over the body, not the products.
Instead of `const products = req.body;` do `const products = req.body.products;`. Supposing that you are using something like express.json() to transform the body into and object.

Comment: The code for map or foreach is missing, but this could be the case.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I updated my post with the code I am using the map, and the error that the Node.js console throws

Comment: It looks to me that you fixed the code according to my answer and now you are presenting a new problem?

Comment: I fixed the code, but it seems to still throw the error cannot read property map of undefined

Comment: It is hard to say what is happening now, since I can’t see the entirety of your code. Also, it is not clear where the console.log happens (I suppose this is what you mean by console outout?). My guess is that in one of the incoming requests body.products in undefined.